# Access browser detection methods inside cell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, browser-detection, rails-cells

I'm using [gem 'cells'](https://github.com/apotonick/cells) and [gem 'browser'](https://github.com/fnando/browser) in my rails 3.2 application. What should I do to access browser gem's methods inside my cells.

I found a solution for devise, which suggests

```
class AuthenticateCell < Cell::Rails 
    include Devise::Controllers::Helpers 
    def login 
      @user = User.new 
      render 
    end 
end
```

What should I need to include to access 'browser' gems methods inside cells

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything and if you did then what error are you getting?

Comment: it says undefined local variable or method `browser' when I try to access browser methods inside cell. 
To circumvent the issue I created new layouts for cells and moved the logic to detect browser in layout view and include cells on basis of browser detection.
But if it's possible to detect browser inside the cell, it'll dry up a lot of code and will be helpful.
I found some soulutions to do that in devise at https://github.com/apotonick/cells/issues/23
but not any for addding browser gem's methods.